# Issue with TeXMaker on win7 and beamer

Tags: beamer, pdf, windows, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

Not sure if this question is appropriate for this forum...

Just wondering if others can confirm this before sending it to the developers.

Setup:

TeXMaker
TeXLive 2012
pdflatex with synctex enabled
embedded internal pdf viewer

Then running pdflatex + view pdf crashes on the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It does not seem to occur if

- synctex is disabled
- internal pdf viewer is *not* embedded

Tested with both Texmaker 4.0 and the previous version.

TeXStudio does not seem to have this problem.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I tried it with my old versions of texmaker (3.2 on Ubuntu with texlive and 3.5.2 on windows with miktex) and it runs fine. After upgrading to the new 4.0 it crashes for me, too. Using MikTeX 2.9 (64bit) on Win8 ... disabling the internal pdf viewer helped here, too.

Comment: Confirmed. Worked fine with 3.2 in Win7, on upgrading to 4.0 it freezes.

Comment: I have tested on Win 7 Professional 64 bit, SP-1  with texlive 2012 updated , md5sum verified `.exe`, default TeXmaker 4.0 installation, `-synctex=1`, `pdfviewer --> built-in and embedded `(internal pdf viewer), save as `.tex` file and run the `pdflatex and view pdf`. It's working fine without crash as following your steps with same TeX distro. PS: i have used [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to clean the registry once i have uninstalled TeXmaker 3.5.2 via controlpanel and before installing TeXMaker4.0. I have tested on TeXmaker portable 4.0 also. It also worked well without crash.

Comment: [TeXmaker author submits 4.0.1 with bugs fixed](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no crash!!
Tested with Texmaker 4.0

[image: Proof here : snapshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Interesting, which os settings is that? I do not recognize the buttons on the the `About Texmaker` window

Comment: @daleif it would be [KDE on any Linux](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmakerlinux.png) see similar [configure window](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02).

Comment: Which of course was not in the question